# Your health and well-being are of paramount concern to us. What does 'of' mean here?

Tags: prepositions, phrase-usage

I received an email from a university and am a bit confused about the sentence below:

> As you’re aware, your health and well-being are **of** paramount concern to us as we look to adopt the latest national and local health advice during the management of this pandemic.

Could *of* be replaced with *a* in that sentence, so that it reads "your health and well-being are **a** paramount concern to us"? This is the way that I would say it on my own, as a non-native English speaker.

Comment: Look up "preposition".

Comment: If replacing *of* with *a*, I think it should be *… are **a** paramount concern **of ours**.*

Comment: This is code for “We are covering our backs”. If you don’t know what “of” means here you should be posting on [ell.se], not here.

Answer (score 2):

**"of paramount concern"** is an prepositional adjectival phrase (an adjunct) and describes the [fundamental] **nature** of "Your health and well-being"[1].

"To us" is a free modifier (adverbial) that modifies the whole clause. The example can be written

"**To us,** your health and well-being are of paramount concern.

[1] Compare, as in my comment above, "The statue is of gold".

Comment: Yes; [Cambridge ED](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/of) has a nicely graded list of examples for this sense, broadening from the central, more physical relation [made out of] to the more immaterial: << **of** [preposition] ... (7): made or consisting of; having [constituting / characterised  by]:
• dresses of lace and silk
• plates of gold and silver
• a land of ice and snow
• a woman of great charm
• a subject of very little interest  >>.

Answer (score 0):

Recall: "of" is a preposition, and prepositions establish relations between nouns. Sometimes, this gives rise to adjectives in the form of phrasal attributives, which an adjective could replace.

> There is a tendency to call a phrase an adjectival phrase when
> that phrase is functioning like an adjective phrase but is not
> actually headed by an adjective. For example, in "Mr. Clinton is a
> ***man of wealth***", the prepositional phrase of wealth modifies a
> man in a manner similar to how an adjective phrase would, and
> it can be reworded with an adjective, e.g. "Mr. Clinton is a
> ***wealthy man***". **A more accurate term for such cases is phrasal
> attributive or attributive phrase.**
>
> — [Adjective Phrase > Adjectival Phrase - Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjective_phrase#:%7E:text=An%20adjective%20phrase%20(or%20adjectival,e.g.%20quite%20upset%20about%20it).)

Let us revert to the question.

> Your health and well-being are of paramount concern to us.

Here, as in the previous cases, "of paramount concern" post-modifies "health" and "well-being" with no adjective heading the phrase—it is a phrasal attributive. Again, we may lose meaning by using a one-word adjective in place of "of paramount concern" as a pre-modifier. Therefore, we use the long phrase, which is just a [phrasal attributive or attributive phrase](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjective_phrase#:%7E:text=An%20adjective%20phrase%20).

Answer (score 0):

If one is to really 'dissect' the sentence, think of it like this: the actual expression is ***[to be a matter of concern](https://www.powerthesaurus.org/of_concern_to/synonyms)***, which is similar to other expressions that have been indicated in the other answers and comments (like for example *a matter of importance*).

Now ***paramount*** simply comes as an enhancer of ***concern***. For this reason, grammatically, you cannot replace *of* with *a* and obtain an identical phrase, the connections between the words are changed. As for the meaning, if you apply this replacement, the sentence does not change its message.

Comment: Nicely said.  Some other examples come to mind: "matter of national security", "person of interest".

Answer (score -1):

Welcome to the site. Good question!

This is a fairly unusual sentence construction in English. It's a structure that's hardly ever used in contemporary, colloquial speech, except in fossilised idioms like:

```
"of paramount concern" or "of utmost importance".
```

It's the possesive/genitive ***of***, the same as the *of* in a phrase like "the Queen of England".

You could think of how this phrase originated like this:

1. A cause **of concern**
2. [Add an adjective] a cause **of paramount concern**
3. [turn the whole phrase into another adjective] a situation **of paramount concern**

The translation into simple English would be:

> Your health and well-being are very important to us

Phrases constructed like this are only used in formal or academic writing generally, except in parts of Southeast England, where they're sometimes used in conversation.

Comment: **1** I'm not convinced that your comments on a North/South divide in British English are accurate or supported by evidence. **2** Neither am I convinced that the construction is at all unusual. **3** The sense of "**of**" is far broader than "possession" - it is more a preposition used to indicate an association, and that association is given by the context. Consider "The statue is of Jesus, it is made of gold"

Comment: Oh deary me! Did you downvote me for that @Greybeard? The "posessive" in the sense of "posessive adjective" includes association as well as ownership or material posession. That's specifically why I included the word 'genitive' beside it.

Comment: I downvoted as, line by line and overall, the answer appears to be vague, inaccurate and have too many generalisations. My list of objections could have been extended.